# How to get cytoscape.js to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, cytoscape.js

I'm having problems getting a very simple cytoscape.js example to work at all. [Here is my code in a pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/pTFQ7p5R)

I'm fairly new to Javascript in general, so this may be a very basic mistake. console.log statements put through the function calls indicate that the cy function is getting properly called and executed, and the browser console doesn't seem t throw any errors, however I cannot get the graph to show. Is there anything that I'm missing in my definition?

I tried to make it as minimalistic as possible. The code is only verbatim copied from some of the cytoscape.js examples. cy.cytoscape is the relevant function. Calling code is at the bottom

```
$('#cy').cytoscape({


.......

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>
```

edit: [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/f8sLh/)

Comment: JSFiddle normally works better...

Comment: Have you got this minimalistic version working? Have you got any basic code working yet?

Comment: Ok. I got it to work after looking at some other Cytoscape.js examples in JSFiddle (great resource, thx for the tip). In this case what I was missing was a css style definition. By only that the example works now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have made some changes in your code.Now it is working fine.
Please look at the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/f8sLh/7/) below

CSS

```
    body { 
      font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    }

    #cy {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
    }
```

JavaScript

```
 $(function() { // on dom ready

        $('#cy').cytoscape({

            style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
                .selector('node')
                .css({
                'content': 'data(name)',
                    'text-valign': 'center',
                    'color': 'white',
                    'text-outline-width': 2,
                    'text-outline-color': '#888'
            })
                .selector('edge')
                .css({
                'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'
            })
                .selector(':selected')
                .css({
                'background-color': 'black',
                    'line-color': 'black',
                    'target-arrow-color': 'black',
                    'source-arrow-color': 'black'
            })
                .selector('.faded')
                .css({
                'opacity': 0.25,
                    'text-opacity': 0
            }),

            elements: {
                nodes: [{
                    data: {
                        id: 'j',
                        name: 'Jerry'
                    }
                }, {
                    data: {
                        id: 'e',
                        name: 'Elaine'
                    }
                }, {
                    data: {
                        id: 'k',
                        name: 'Kramer'
                    }
                }, {
                    data: {
                        id: 'g',
                        name: 'George'
                    }
                }],
                edges: [{
                    data: {
                        source: 'j',
                        target: 'e'
                    }
                }, {
                    data: {
                        source: 'j',
                        target: 'k'
                    }
                }, {
                    data: {
                        source: 'j',
                        target: 'g'
                    }
                }, {
                    data: {
                        source: 'e',
                        target: 'j'
                    }
                }, {
                    data: {
                        source: 'e',
                        target: 'k'
                    }
                }, {
                    data: {
                        source: 'k',
                        target: 'j'
                    }
                }, {
                    data: {
                        source: 'k',
                        target: 'e'
                    }
                }, {
                    data: {
                        source: 'k',
                        target: 'g'
                    }
                }, {
                    data: {
                        source: 'g',
                        target: 'j'
                    }
                }]
            },

            ready: function() {
                window.cy = this;

                // giddy up...

                cy.elements().unselectify();

                cy.on('tap', 'node', function(e) {
                    var node = e.cyTarget;
                    var neighborhood = node.neighborhood().add(node);

                    cy.elements().addClass('faded');
                    neighborhood.removeClass('faded');
                });

                cy.on('tap', function(e) {
                    if (e.cyTarget === cy) {
                        cy.elements().removeClass('faded');
                    }
                });
            }

        });

    }); // on dom ready
```

HTML

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/api/cytoscape.js-latest/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/api is broken in 2019.... how can i get it nowadays?

Comment: http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/api/cytoscape.js-latest/cytoscape.min.js this url returns 404 error